# How to fix TypeError "cannot read property 'x' of null" at Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, properties

I have a working React app, including alert functionality, but when I try to compile for production it throws a type error.

I've included the code for my alert reducer, action, and component below:

Reducer

```
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = [{}];

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  const merged = { ...initialState, ...state };

  switch (type) {
    case SET_ALERT:
      return [...state, payload];
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      return merged.filter(alert => alert.id !== payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Action

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types';

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => dispatch => {
  const id = uuid.v4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id }
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};
```

Component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Alert = ({ alerts }) =>
  alerts !== null &&
  alerts.length > 1 &&
  alerts.slice(1).map(alert => (
    <div key='alert.id' className={`alert alert-${alert.alertType}`}>
      {alert.msg}
    </div>
  ));

Alert.propTypes = {
  alerts: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  alerts: state.alert
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Alert);
```

The error message is says:

```
./src/reducers/alert.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: `{ ...initialState, ...state }` should be `[ ...initialState, ...state ]`, but also, that will always put an empty object at the start.

Comment: `.filter` does not mutate the original array, so `merged` is useless here.

Comment: I removed merged and called state.filter directly as I did before, but this does not really change anything; I still have the original problem. Is there some way to type check for null and handle accordingly?

Comment: In your reducer code, it seems that `merged` is defined as an object, but then you are using `filter` method on it, which does not exist for object. Maybe a typo when posting your code?
Also, is that your complete code for the _src/reducers/alert.js_ file? By the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` it seems that you are trying to read a `name` property somewhere, which does not happen in your code.

Comment: I removed merged in the end, just filtering over state. The complete code of the reducer is what I've posted. I've checked every file where setAlert is called, and can't find it referencing name anywhere. Is there any workaround for this the way it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same error as you , this is what i do :

```
import uuid from "uuid";
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from "../types";

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => dispatch => {
  const id = uuid.v4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: [{ msg, alertType, id }]
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};

import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from "../types";
const initialState = [];

export default function(state = initialState, { type, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    case SET_ALERT:
      return payload;
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      return [];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and do a clean git init and Voilà , this is my repo for the course https://github.com/syahmiyani/devlepak

Answer (score 0):

Change your **Reducer** to below code. You need to give the function name.

```
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = [{}];

const alert = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  const merged = { ...initialState, ...state };

  switch (type) {
    case SET_ALERT:
      return [...state, payload];
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      return merged.filter(alert => alert.id !== payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default alert;
```